# cmake install does not trigger custom command

Tags: c++, c, cmake

In my project I use add_custom_command to generate some output file:

```
    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${LIB_NAME}
        # commands
    )
    add_custom_target(Core-static DEPENDS ${LIB_NAME})
```

I then have instruction to install the library:

```
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${LIB_NAME}"
        DESTINATION "${CORE_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/"
)
```

When I manualy build Core-static target, I can then successfuly run installation. However, running install does not trigger the custom command and the library is not produced resulting in an error. Also, for some reason rebuilding the solution (in Visual Studio) does not trigger Core-static project build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CMake, installing triggers **only** *ALL* (pseudo-)target.

For make your file installable, you need to force *ALL* target to build your file. Currently, your custom target `Core-static` is not buit by default (by *ALL* target). For fix that, add `ALL` keyword when create the target:

```
add_custom_target(Core-static ALL DEPENDS ${LIB_NAME})
```